# Is it possible to restore database from S3 bucket in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

We are running Marklogic on a non AWS instance. One of our data-base backup is in S3 bucket. Is it possible to directly restore from the S3 bucket. Currently we are downloading the backup and then restoring it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to restore from an S3 bucket from a server that is not an AWS EC2 instance.

You would need to configure the S3 endpoint and credentials in your group settings, so that MarkLogic knows how to authenticate when talking to your S3 bucket.

> ## [Configure the S3 Endpoint for your Group](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ec2/managing#id_51735)
>
> The S3 Endpoint is configured by specifying the S3 properties for your MarkLogic group.
>
> - Log into the Admin Interface.
> - Click the name of your group under the Groups icon on the left tree menu.
> - In the Group Configuration page, scroll down to the bottom to locate the S3 fields:
>   [image]

> ## [Configure AWS Credentials](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ec2/managing#id_26769)
>
> In order to use AWS you must supply AWS credentials. You can configure AWS credentials in one of three ways:
>
> - [Configuring an IAM Role with an AWS Access Policy](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ec2/managing#id_77726)
> - [Configuring AWS Credentials in Environment Variables](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ec2/managing#id_35499)
> - [Configuring AWS Credentials in the Security Database](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ec2/managing#id_64674)

If you are trying to access S3 from a server outside of AWS that isn't an EC2 instance, then you won't have an IAM Role and would want to configure the credentials either in the Security database or Environment Variables.

> If you are only using S3, it is best to use the Admin Interface to store your AWS credentials because the credentials are securely stored in the MarkLogic Security database.
>
> In the Security, Credentials, Configure tab are fields for specifying the AWS credentials.
>
> Log into the Admin Interface.
>
> - Click Security icon on the left tree menu.
> - Click Credentials to open the Credential Configuration page.
> - Enter the aws access key, aws secret key, and optional aws session token provided for your AWS account.
>   [image]

Comment: I have done all this but when I try to restore the db form S3 url the page just hangs. I don't see anything in the logs as well. The backup size is just 24MB. 
Below is the format of S3 url I have used `s3://<bucket-name>/<backup-directory>/`